# How to find matching keys in an object where each key's value is an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to find the most efficient way to search an object, where each value is an array of arrays.  The search function would recieve an array `[0,1,0]`, find all items that contain this array, and return an array of matching keys.

```js
var items = {
  "bob":[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]],
  "joe":[[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]],
  "ike":[[0,0,0],[0,0,2],[1,1,1]]
}
```

for example

- `[0,0,0]` would return `["bob","joe","ike"]`
- `[0,1,0]` would return `["bob","joe"]`
- `[1,1,1]` would return `["joe","ike"]`
- `[0,0,2]` would return `["ike"]`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? And what exactly are you trying to make "most efficient"? (time, lines of code, etc)

Comment: This is not a code writing service, So please do some research and share your efforts of what you have done.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the keys of the object. In every property, create a `hash` from its value, then using [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), check if the target subarray is in it, which will determine whether to include the current key or not in the resulting list:

```js
const getMatchingProps = (obj = {}, subArr = []) => 
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((matchingKeys, key) => {
    const hash = obj[key].reduce((acc, arr, i) => ({ ...acc, [arr]: i }), {});
    return hash.hasOwnProperty(subArr) ? [...matchingKeys, key] : matchingKeys
  }, []);

const items = {
  "bob": [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]],
  "joe": [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]],
  "ike": [[0,0,0],[0,0,2],[1,1,1]]
};

console.log( getMatchingProps(items, [0,0,0]).join() );
console.log( getMatchingProps(items, [0,1,0]).join() );
console.log( getMatchingProps(items, [1,1,1]).join() );
console.log( getMatchingProps(items, [0,0,2]).join() );
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get the result that you want, but it may not be the most efficient speedwise. It is short though.

```js
const items = {
    bob: [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
    ],
    joe: [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0],
    ],
    ike: [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2],
        [1, 1, 1],
    ],
};
const test = (items, target) => {
    return Object.entries(items)
        .filter((item) => {
            return item[1].some((list) => {
                return (
                    list.length === target.length &&
                    list.every((number, index) => {
                        return number === target[index];
                    })
                );
            });
        })
        .map((item) => {
            return item[0];
        });
};

console.log(test(items, [0, 0, 0])); // [ 'bob', 'joe', 'ike' ]
console.log(test(items, [0, 1, 0])); // [ 'bob', 'joe' ]
console.log(test(items, [1, 1, 1])); // [ 'joe', 'ike' ]
console.log(test(items, [0, 0, 2])); // [ 'ike' ]
```

**Explanation**: Use `Object.entries()` to get the keys and values of `items`. Then filter out that list using the `some` function, where there has to be some array in the value list where the array equals the target array. In this case, to see if the arrays are equal, I checked that the lengths were equal and that all the numbers were equal using `every`. After the entries list is filtered, we then use `map` to just get the names out.